# Spelling Error on 404 page

Tags: bug, status-declined, spelling

> Occasionally questions or answers may
>   be removed from Stack Overflow for
>   reasons of moderation: spam, off
>   topic, abuse, etcetera.

*Et cetera* is two words, not one, as it come from the Latin meaning "and others".

<sub>Yes, I'm being overly pedantic here, but it should still be fixed.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no need to fix it at all:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/etcetera

Just because it comes from two words in Latin doesn't mean it's not one word in English. English is the original Embrace, Extend, Exterminate language.

Comment: I hate to concede a point, but you are right. I was not aware that the one-word spelling is also used. *Nevertheless*, since we have two spellings here, and the two-word one is both etymologically correct (regardless of the fact that English is not Latin) and more commonly used (e.g. Google search results), I still propose that it be changed to the two-word spelling.

Answer (score 13):

I remember the old days when you didn't need to know **latin** to be a programmer :P

Comment: Not everything was in English in the old days. Remember MSDN?

Comment: +1 for" the old days" coming from a 16 year old person :D

Comment: +1 for "the old days" coming from a 14 year old person. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is **MAJOR**.  It will be fixed in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: That's a conservative estimate.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera

> The one-word spelling "etcetera" is commonly used, and is accepted as correct by many dictionaries

Surely there are more *important* things for us to be concerned about or working on?

Comment: Assuming you saw my comment of Randolpho's answer and still understand why I still think it should be corrected, surely it would have taken just as much time to fix it as to find a quote on WP and decline it?

Comment: You can't trust Wikipedia! Anyone can edit it!